# Dynamically populated select menu on html page to be displayed on android webview without using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-apps-script, google-caja

I made a web app using google apps script and deployed it on the web. The application works well on PC, but when I load it to a webview on android, the dynamically populated `<select>` menus are not displayed (they are empty).

I know that google caja has an issue with jquery mobile from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1665&can=1&q=jquery&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), so I cannot use jquery mobile.

The question is if there is a way to make that `<select>` menus work using only jquery or javascript? Or maybe I can do some trick in android?

Here is an example of how I populate the menu using jquery:

```
function addClients(clients){   //array of options from google spreadsheets.
  $('#client').empty();
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#client').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
    $('#client').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
}
```

HTML part:

```
<select name="client" id="client" data-native-menu="true" data-role="none">
    <option> ---- Choose a client ----</option>
</select>
```

Android part:

```
WebView myWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.loadUrl("--- my web app's URL here ---");
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Thank you in advance.

### EDIT:

It looks kile the menu is not refreshing. At the beginning I have a built-in option:

```
<option> ---- Choose a client ----</option>
```

This option is deleted in jquery part, but then the menu is not updated, it stays empty.

I've already tried with no positive result:

```
$('#client').trigger("chosen:updated");

$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

$('#client').hide();
$('#client').show();

$('select#client').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. What I did is commented the line which emptied the select menu and used jquery ui for my purpose:

```
function addClients(clients){   //array of options from google spreadsheets.
  //$('#client').empty(); ---------- I commented this.
  for (var i in clients) {
    $('#client').append('<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>');
   // $('#client').trigger("chosen:updated"); ------- This line is also removed
  }
$(function() {  // And added jquery ui select menu
  $( "#client" ).selectmenu();
  });
}
```

This did the job. I'm not sure why though...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, it is absolutely possible. (Almost) everything jQuery does uses native HTML/CSS/JavaScript functionalities in the background. As a framework it just exists to make your coding quicker and easier.

Assumming you select has id "client", you can select it using `var selectClient = document.getElementById("client");`.

I don't know where you're getting your options from (manually entered, or loaded from through a PHP API call, or from a database, etc.), so I'm going to assume you have access to the options you want to add.

Adding options to the client can be done by using

```
selectClient.innerHTML += "<option>My option here</option>";
```

The "innerHTML" property basically holds everything between `<select>` and `</select>`.

If you want to remove existing options before adding new ones, just set innerHTML to an empty "" string first.
If you want to edit a specific option tag you need to use any of the native or jQuery methods for finding a tag (or an ID if you add ID's to the options) to select the option.

Hope this helps.

P.S. This solution is pure JavaScript, but you can of course use any equivalent jQuery functions if the platform supports it. The jQuery equivalent of the `innerHTML` property is `html()`, as in `$("#client").html("<option>Foo Bar</option>");`

EDIT 04-08-2014: as it turns out the OP wasn't using the plugin whose events he was calling (Chosen for jQuery), but the steps described above are still correct and still apply (if not using Chosen).

Comment: It didn't work. What I changed:  `'function addClients(clients){  
  $('#client').empty();  
  var clientOptions = document.getElementById("client");  
  for (var i in clients) {  
    clientOptions.innerHTML += '<option>'+clients[i]+'</option>';  
  }  
}' `   But in android I still get empty pop-up of `<select>` menu.

Comment: You failed to mention you are using the Chosen jQuery plugin. Chosen initialises the select with it's own functionalities when you call the chosen() (or something like that) method on a select. I'd guess the problem is in the order you do this in. Try and do all the manipulations of the select **before** you Chosen-ify it.

Comment: @keshet Also, try and perform the same code in a "normal" web environment (for example make a JS fiddle). If your code works there then the issue is Android specific, in which case you will usually have to carefully consider a few methods to try it and check them one by one. I recommend keeping track of what you tried in a small list so you don't lose oversight and can quickly see if there are still things you didn't try.

Comment: As I mentioned, in "normal" web environment, on PC, this web app works just fine. The problem indeen on the android's side. I tried to refresh the select not only with chosen(), but the outcome didn't change. Also, if I open this web app on my android, using a web browser, everything works OK. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I get the feeling the interaction between Chosen and Google Caja isn't going well, seeing as Caja is a security module imposing certain restrictions etc. on third party plugins. I think the communication between those 2 isn't working. Try and remove Chosen, using just native JS or JS with jQuery first. If that doesn't work either you may report it as an issue to Google, but I suspect the problem won't be an issue without Chosen.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not sure what is that "chosen" thing you're talking about. My imports are: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @keshet [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is a plugin which allows you to easily make nicely styled inputs of various types. However, if you don't know what it is and/or are not using it, why are you specifically calling Chosen-plugin-specific events ("chosen:updated")?